# How can you climb up, or stick to, other objects in Box2D?

Tags: flash, box2d

I know that trying to model character movement in Box2D is always hard/impossible, but I'm trying to see if there's any way to make an user-controlled object that cleanly slides against other objects, going up or down, that makes it look like the character is climbing/walking up or a down.

The character could be modelled as a circle if that simplifies matters, but I don't see how I could get this effect using just a circle with a joint motor. There's a "wheel joint" in the C++ version of Box2d, which I suppose I could port to Flash, but I don't know if that would give the correct effect either.

Another idea I had was to have the character do little jumps, based on the normal of the object that it is touching. But I suspect that at corners, or at contacts with multiple objects, this will give weird results.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: is this for a side scroller, or top view?

Comment: @RuiCampos for a side scroller

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the little jumps, you can avoid the weird results with multiple objects by using collision groups. You only calculate the normal of the object, and subsequent jump, on objects which belong to a certain group.

Tell me if you need help setting these collision groups, though I'm not familiar with the flash port.